# How is 'duration' being computed when 'departureTime' is specified?

Tags: rest, here-api, here-maps-rest

I'm using Routing REST API V8 to collect travel time data. I understand that 'duration' returns the total amount of travel time at a specified departure time depending on traffic. What is the difference between requesting a departure time in the future and in the past?

My guess is that for future 'departureTime', 'duration' is an estimation. In that case, is it possible to know how was this estimated? Also, for past 'departureTime', what it returns is some kind of historical travel time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no difference between requesting a departure time in the future and in the past for both is utilizing the Traffic Pattern database where describes the statistically driven speed for each quarter of an hour for each day of the week. The traffic pattern database has own algorithm to update itself from historical travel time.

When you set parameter departureTime in between one hour of current time then is utilized the current traffic situation on the road otherwise whether for a future or for the past is using Traffic Pattern database.